# How to get value from static method in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

In my typescript, there is a method added in `static`. later I am trying to call the same. But getting error... while compile the code. anything wrong with my code? any one help me to understand the `static` properties in `typescript`?

Here is my code :

```
class Car { 
    private distanceRun: number = 0;
    color: string;

    constructor(public hybrid:boolean, color:string="red") {
        this.color = color;
    }

    getGasConsumption():string { 
        return this.hybrid ? "Low" : "High";
    }

    drive(distance:number) {
        return this.distanceRun += distance;
    }

    static horn():string {
        return "HOOONK!";
    }

    get distance():number {
        return this.distanceRun;
    }

}

let newCar = new Car(false);
console.log(newCar.color);
console.log(newCar.horn()); //shows error as Property 'horn' does not exist on type 'Car'..
```

[Live](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Car%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20distanceRun%3A%20number%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20hybrid%3Aboolean%2C%20color%3Astring%3D%22red%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.color%20%3D%20color%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getGasConsumption()%3Astring%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.hybrid%20%3F%20%22Low%22%20%3A%20%22High%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20drive(distance%3Anumber)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.distanceRun%20%2B%3D%20distance%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20horn()%3Astring%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22HOOONK!%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20distance()%3Anumber%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.distanceRun%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20newCar%20%3D%20new%20Car(false)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(newCar.color)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(newCar.horn())%3B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static members are not attached to the instances of the class. They are attached to the class itself.

You need to call static methods and properties via class, not it's intance -   like this`Car.horn()`.

**[Live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Car%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20distanceRun%3A%20number%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20hybrid%3Aboolean%2C%20color%3Astring%3D%22red%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.color%20%3D%20color%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getGasConsumption()%3Astring%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.hybrid%20%3F%20%22Low%22%20%3A%20%22High%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20drive(distance%3Anumber)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.distanceRun%20%2B%3D%20distance%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20horn()%3Astring%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22HOOONK!%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20distance()%3Anumber%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.distanceRun%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20newCar%20%3D%20new%20Car(false)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(newCar.color)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(Car.horn())%3B)**

You can see, that

```
class Test {
   get() { 

   }

   static getStatic() {

   }
}
```

is compiled into this

```
function Test() {

}

Test.prototype.get = function () {

};

Test.getStatic = function () {

};
```

From this it is obvious that `getStatic` is in the `Test` itself, while `get` is in the prototype of the `Test`, which will be referenced from the objects, created via `Test` *function-constructor*.

Comment: I was writing same thing

Comment: @Suren Srapyan - I agreed with you. But what is the reason the `class` keeping the `static` like this? any special requirement or reason? what is the correct use of `static` ? can you please and in your answer?

Comment: `static` should be those fields that are not related to each object. For example, you can have a `Point` class, which has a static method with name `addPoints`. This can accept Point objects, add them together and return that. Because this method is related to Points, from the encapsulation view you can make it as static and put in the `Point` class